# Trying to move the flexslider controls to the middle of the slider window

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a theme in wordpress that is using flexslider. Unfortunately the way it's set up the controls and the title appear at the bottom of the slider window. I'd like to move the controls for the slider to the middle of the slider (one on each side) and the shaded title bar to the top.

I've tried reading the documentation but I couldn't find what I was looking for, and fiddling with the css in inspector didn't change anything either. Any help on figuring out how to do this would be great.

Here's my site as it stands with the slider running

http://test.encorelab.org/

Comment: You need to have demonstrated some basic understanding of the underlying technologies. Show us some example jQuery or CSS of what you've tried, and reduce your code sample to just the relevant snippet, rather than linking to a full page and making us wade through it.

Comment: Not sure what you want from a "basic understanding" but I've done a bunch of sites before and sliders (I did this page on this site http://test.encorelab.org/projects.html and have done sliders before such as http://shalu.miketissenbaum.com/place.html - excuse the look of the second one I'm waiting on feedback from the designer). I admit I'm a bit new at custom tweaking sliders in wordpress, but I can't find which parts or the CSS let me move these two items around within flexslider div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the flexslider.css and make the following changes:

```
.flex-caption {
    bottom: 0px /* REMOVE THIS LINE */
    top:0px; /* ADD THIS */
}

.flex-direction-nav li .prev {
    left: 0;
    top: 48%;
}

.flex-direction-nav li .next{
    right: 0;
    top: 48%;
}
```

Ideally you should just completely strip out everything in flexslider.css and do it all from scratch to minimise bloat, but the above will provide you with what you need in the short term :)

Would also suggest you familiarise yourself with Chrome Developer Tools - a web developers best friend!

Comment: Thanks man - this really helped! Needed to get some extra write permission from my admin (which was part of the problem too),

also needed to add a background-position `.flex-direction-nav li .next {right: 0; background-position: -32px 0; top: 48%}
`

because both buttons are on the same png for the theme - again really helpful